# PhpStorm is not starting up

Tags: phpstorm

I just downloaded PhpStorm 5 on my quite fresh ubuntu.
During the first start I installed a couple of plug-ins.
Now - after the installation of those plug-ins - PhpStorm is not starting up anymore.
No splash screen is showing up. No error gets written on the terminal:

```
gue@ubuntu:~$ phpstorm
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
gue@ubuntu:~$
```

What shall I do with that drunken sailor?
I can't find any logfiles, no configuration file/directory in my home directory.

Since I'm used to Eclipse I've no clue where to look for a trace in this IntelliJ derivate...

Comment: You could try `strace phpstorm` to see what it's doing. Be prepared to be inundated with output.

Comment: You have installed JVM on 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: Delete the plug-ins manually, [see the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181) for the directory location on your system.

Comment: @Mike here is my stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/FvjBqDLF

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks for the link. Actually it doesn't help too much. After fiddling with the plugins directory of PhpStorm I extracted the whole application newly for the download tar.gz. Even with a totally fresh PhpStorm it won't start up.
I guess there is something more than just the application folder. Something I haven't deleted/overwritten while re-extracting the app..

Comment: Delete `~/.WebIde50` directory.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you. That was it. It seems something was messed up inside that directory. And since I haven't done much customization of my PhpStorm it was nothing important I lost by deleting that directory.

Comment: @CrazyCoder; Please note you will lose all your settings, projects listings and registration key. But i was able to start PHPStorm again..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some plug-ins can cause problems and prevent IDE from starting, if it happens, you should delete the directory containing plug-in manually. Location of this directory depends on the system and product, [details are available in the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181).

For PhpStorm on Linux it would be `~/.WebIde50/config/plugins`.

Answer (score 20):

If you're on Windows deleting the following directory helped me:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\
```

Comment: Helped me also.

Comment: worked for me too..

Answer (score 7):

This happend to me too, I had created a custom vmoptions file, and entered incorrect values. I fixed it by deleting it in `~/.WebIde50/phpstorm.vmoptions`

Answer (score 4):

i  had the same problem ,  i fixed it just with removing the file C:\Users\.PhpStorm2016.2

Answer (score 4):

In linux, I fixed it by deleting vmoptions file of PhpStorm and then launching it again:

```
mv  ~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm*/phpstorm64.vmoptions ~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm*/__phpstorm64.vmoptions
```

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal Linux Ubuntu 20.04 and execute

```
pkill -9 -fei phpstorm
phpstorm
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to remove all `cache` for the IDE located in:

```
~/.cache/JetBrains/
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the VMOptions under the Help menu on MacOS and it just would not start up again. It just silently failed every time. I found the file at `/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/phpstorm` and ran it in the terminal, which gave me an output with the following error:

```
Invalid ReservedCodeCacheSize=3072M. Must be at most 2048M.
```

Luckily, it also gave me the path to the VMOptions file in one of the rows of the output, `parseVMOptions: /Users/barnabas/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PhpStorm2022.3/phpstorm.vmoptions` in my case, so I could change it back to a valid configuration. Crisis averted.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible if openjdk is installed then phpstorm not opened.

So remove first then follow steps that given in below link.
I solve the problem same way.

wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Installing_and_running_PHPStorm_on_Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you fix this: Rename C:\Users\USERNAME.PhpStorm2016.3 to something else (anything, like PhpStorm2016.whatever) , it will start the program if you click on the phpStorm icon, then choose to import settings, and you're good to go ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am using PhpStorm2020.2.1. I referred to [Configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html?_ga=2.156315643.1385029791.1600828916-374460765.1600828916#plugins-directory). I accessed the folder `%AppData%\JetBrains\PhpStorm2020.2`, renamed it just in case I may need some files in future.

Voila! I can start my PhpStorm2020.2.1 again!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem yesterday and my OS is windows 10. phpStorm suddenly did not work and when I click on it nothing happened. I just downloaded JDK from this link (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) and after installation, I set the environment value in the system setting for my java directory. You can use this link to set the environment (https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10)

Answer (score -1):

Simple
Go to your task manager
end any task on php-storm
and restart the ide again
it will work

Answer (score -3):

Open Terminal Linux Ubuntu 20.10

1. `YOU@USER:~$ cd ~/.config`
2. `YOU@USER:~/.config$ ls`

Obs: Locate the >>> **JetBrains** <<< folder, after that delete it your default app settings will disappear more it will open again

3. `YOU@USER:~/.config$ sudo rm -rf JetBrains/`
4. Open ***PHPSTORM***